# Windows Right Click Menu - Is it possible to add an empty line / space above and below Paste option?

Tags: context-menu, right-click

Windows Right Click Menu - Is it possible to add an empty line / space above and below Paste option ?

For example via Registry Database

And if it is possible, this whole enhanced big area would the Paste button

[image: End result would be like this]

Comment: That appears to be Windows 10. Consider upgrading to Windows 11.  Context Menus are better spaced and set up.

Comment: Also, you didn't explain the purpose. Maybe you just need to enable (on Windows 100 or 11) the touch-optimized layout, which will give you much more in the context menus (and elsewhere)

Comment: Consider changing the menu *font* size, https://ittutorials.net/software/os/windows-10/increase-font-size-menus-windows-10/ . That would also increase line spacing, but throughout the menu.

Comment: My purpose is to have a larger Paste button for very quick clicking, I do a lot of paste operations. Often hitting Paste shortcut accidentally. So purpose is avoid hitting else then Paste

Comment: Consider using the control+v keyboard shortcut

Comment: I also use Ctrl+V,

Comment: I also use Ctrl+V (a lot), but I also use a lot the Right Click Menu Paste command, sorry but this forum and Q is not a place to provide a several hundreds pages company standard guidebook grade documentation about my usage of PC, and also I'm not meant to do that, if I'm asking this Q, it means I use a lot the Right Click Menu Paste command, therefore that is the Q, and I need answer for that Q.